# The specified CGI application misbehaved... when executing hgweb.cgi for Mercurial

Tags: python, mercurial, cgi, iis-6, hgweb

- I have IIS 6
- I installed Mercurial in c:/program files/mercurial
- I installed Python 2.6 in c:/program files/python
- I added extension handlings etc for my websites under tab 'home directory'=>'configuration

  - "C:\program files\Mercurial\python\python.exe" -u "%s" "%s"
  - extenstion = .cgi
- I allowed python.exe in web service extensions

  - "C:\Program Files\Mercurial\Python\python.exe" -u "%s" "%s"
- I allowed all unknown cgi, although it is not recommended for security reasons
- I have a website on E:\WWW\
  -I have a repository on E:\WWW\

Then I try to access http://localhost/hgweb.cgi and I get this error:

"The specified CGI application misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers"

Please, help for I am getting pretty frustrated.
Thanks a lot!

Maarten / Netherlands

Comment: Are there any logs you could look at that would contain relevant information?

Comment: Solved! Somehow...sorry, but I just went into the configs again and suddenly it worked. First I added the headers manually using python commands like 'print' and it got me to see the errormessage. Then I uncommented the line which would give me detailed information about errors. Then I uncommented each line seperately and found out it was the location of the repository or config. Not sure which exactly. Bottom line is I guess to uncomment the errormessaging so you get to see detailed errorinfo. AND: uncomment every line until the error disappears.