# Mercurial failed to load in IIS 7 on windows 2008

Tags: iis, mercurial, windows-server-2008

Trying to setup Mercurial on windows 2008 using IIS 7. Followed the instruction from the following links,

http://stackingcode.com/blog/2011/02/24/running-a-mercurial-server-on-iis-7-5-windows-server-2008-r2

http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/

After the setup, when I try to load the hgweb.cgi page, I keep having the error "DLL failed loading". Bellow shows the full error message.

From the error, it quite hard to know which DLL is missing. I have tried to find the missing DLL, but do not succeed. Has anyone having the same problem before? What's the missing DLL?

I'm using Murcurial 2.0 and python 2.6 with the precompiled installer. Tried both x86 and x64 installer, still has the same problem.

> HTTP Error 502.2 - Bad Gateway The specified CGI application
>   misbehaved by not returning a complete set of HTTP headers. The
>   headers it did return are "Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\hg\hgweb.cgi", line 24, in  application =
>   hgweb(config) File "mercurial\hgweb__init__.pyc", line 26, in hgweb
>   File "mercurial\hgweb\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 89, in **init** File
>   "mercurial\hgweb\hgwebdir_mod.pyc", line 98, in refresh File
>   "mercurial\ui.pyc", line 43, in **init** File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 86, in **getattribute** File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 58, in _load File
>   "mercurial\scmutil.pyc", line 164, in  File
>   "mercurial\scmutil.pyc", line 180, in opener File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 86, in **getattribute** File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 58, in _load File
>   "mercurial\util.pyc", line 27, in  File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 86, in **getattribute** File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 58, in _load File
>   "mercurial\windows.pyc", line 13, in  File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 86, in **getattribute** File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 58, in _load File
>   "mercurial\win32.pyc", line 11, in  File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 86, in **getattribute** File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 58, in _load File
>   "ctypes__init__.pyc", line 10, in  File
>   "mercurial\demandimport.pyc", line 114, in _demandimport File
>   "_ctypes.pyc", line 12, in  File "_ctypes.pyc", line 10, in
>   __load ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. ".

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191136/hosting-mercurial-with-iis-6 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177810/the-specified-cgi-application-misbehaved-when-executing-hgweb-cgi-for-mercuri or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123798/error-setting-up-mercurial-on-windows-server-2008 didn't help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318970/mercurial-cgi-hgweb-cgi-fails can help too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The first link talked about changed to used `c:\whatever\Python26\python.exe -u -O -B "%s" "%s"`. It works now. This is really a mysterious since all documentations shows wrong instructions.